# How to make data unreadable once the time indicated on its time stamp has passed?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, time

Let’s say for instance a user writes about an event to the Firebase database, what the user writes has a time stamp attached to it and other users are able to read what was written in a list view using the FirebaseListAdapter. Is there a way to make the data written by the user unreadable once the time on the time stamp has passed?

Comment: Wow, thank you, I will try it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a big difference here between whether you have a single item, or a list of items.

## Securing access to a single node

If you have a single node like this in your database:

```
"content": {
  "expiresAt": 1565275079920,
  "content": "This content is only readable until Thu Aug 08 2019 07:37:59 GMT-0700"
}
```

You can ensure this node is only readable until its expiry timestamp with these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "content": {
      ".read": "data.child('expiresAt').val() < now"
    }
  }
}
```

When somebody attaches a listener to `/content` up until the expiry timestamp it will be allowed, after that any new listeners will be rejected.

---

## Securing access to a list of nodes

But things get more complicated when you have a list of data as:

1. You can only read/query data if you have read access to all that data.
2. Once you have read access to a node, you have read access to all data under that node.

Combined these two fact mean that security rules cannot be used to filter data.

So if you have a list of these nodes above:

```
"content": {
  "-Ldshdh13...": {
    "expiresAt": 1565275079920,
    "content": "This content is only readable until Thu Aug 08 2019 07:37:59 GMT-0700"
  },
  "-Ldshdh13...": {
    "expiresAt": 1565277079920,
    "content": "This content is only readable until Thu Aug 08 2019 08:11:19 GMT-0700"
  },
  ...
}
```

In order to be able to query this data, the user must have read permission on `/content`. And as soon as they have full read permission on `/content`, you can't keep them from reading certain nodes under there.

The only way to make this scenario work is to use a combination of a query and a security rule that validates this query.

**Step 1: query for only the data that you're allowed to read**

So if you should only be able to read data that expires in the future:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('content');
ref.orderByChild('expiresAt').startAt(Date.now()).once('value',...
```

**Step 2: use security rules to only allow reads with this query**

The security rules will now check whether the user is passing the correct `orderBy` and value in to their query so that they're only accessing non-expired data:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "content": {
      ".read": "query.orderByChild == 'expiresAt' &&
                query.startAt >= now"
    }
  }
}
```

A few things still to note:

- The security are applied when the listener is attached. So the value of `now` is only checked at that moment, it doesn't get modified in any way after that. This is usually not a security problem, but means you will need to remove outdated data in the application code too after attaching the listener.
- You may need to tweak the rule a bit, as the `Date.now()` in the client and the `now` in the rules may not be exactly the same. Adding a few seconds in the security rule may be a good idea.

For further reading, I highly recommend:

- [documentation on the fact that permissions cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade)
- [documentation on rules-are-not-filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters)
- previous [questions on rules are not filters](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+rules+are+not+filters). Note that many of these probably predate the introduction of query-based security rules.
- [documentation on query based security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules)

Comment: sorry to disturb you in anyway, but I am kindly asking if you could show me how to do the code.             'var ref = firebase.database().ref('content');
ref.orderByChild('expiresAt').startAt(Date.now()).once(...... '                          in Java

Comment: The Firebase API is fairly consistent across platforms. Since you didn't tag your question with any language, I answered in JavaScript because it's typically most concise. If you're having a hard time implementing this in Java, edit your question to show what you tried (or post a new question) and somebody may be able to help.

Comment: Alright, thank you, I will try that, I actually tried searching the documentation under query but I couldn't find any examples in java or with .'once('value...'

Comment: Check the documentation for Android [reading data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once).